# How do I organise my projects while working without an IDE?

Tags: java, ide, organization, projects

I have a program in which I studied and tried out the Observer Pattern.

I wrote it with nano on my terminal, and I saved it like this:

```
kneipe
    (location
       (Show.java))
    (leute
       (Beobachter.java
       Comedian.java))
```

I compiled correctly all of them but it keeps saying that in my main the references to the classes aren't right so it can't make new `Object`s from the other classes.

Here is the deal:
I tried it out on eclipse and it works fine with `import package2.*;`

And all of the tutorials I found online or even in books are only with one package-folder.

So, how do I organise my project and how do I import correctly because I tried (almost) everything and nothing worked so far (I even tried copying the second package into the first, which didn't work either).

ClassA:

```
package leute;

import java.util.*;

public class Comedian extends Observable {
    String name = "";
    int numGags = 0;
    String joke = "abc";
    boolean toldjoke = false;

    public Comedian(String name, int numGags) {
        this.name = name;
        this.numGags = numGags;
    }

    public void telljoke() {
        this.toldjoke = true;
        System.out.println(joke);
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers();
    }

    private String getname() {
        return this.name;
    }

    private int getnumgags() {
        return this.numGags;
    }
    }
```

Thats ClassB:

```
package leute;

import java.util.*;

public class Besucher implements Observer {
    String name = "";
    int intus = 0;
    boolean lacht = false; 

    public Besucher(String name, int intus) {
        this.name = name;
        this.intus = intus;
    }

    private String getname() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void enought(Besucher a) {
        a.lacht = false; 
    }

    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        lacht = true;
        System.out.println("HAHAHAH!!!");
    }
}
```

Thats the Main:

```
package location;

import leute.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Show {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Observer franz = new Besucher("Franz", 6);
        Observer karl = new Besucher("Karl", 1);
        Comedian mark = new Comedian("Mark", 5);

        mark.addObserver(franz);

        mark.telljoke();


        mark.addObserver(karl);

        mark.telljoke();

        mark.deleteObserver(karl);
        mark.deleteObserver(franz);

        mark.telljoke();
    }
}
```

As mentioned it works fine on eclipse but the terminal tells me this:

```
lisaundamelia@lisaundamelia ~/Schreibtisch/Alle Projekte $ javac
  kneipe/location/Show.java
kneipe/location/Show.java:3: error: package leute does not exist
import leute.Besucher;
            ^
kneipe/location/Show.java:4: error: package leute does not exist
import leute.Comedian;
            ^
kneipe/location/Show.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
        Observer franz = new Besucher("Franz", 6);
                             ^
  symbol:   class Besucher
  location: class Show
kneipe/location/Show.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
        Observer karl = new Besucher("Karl", 1);
                            ^
  symbol:   class Besucher
  location: class Show
kneipe/location/Show.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
        Comedian mark = new Comedian("Mark", 5);
        ^
  symbol:   class Comedian
  location: class Show
kneipe/location/Show.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
        Comedian mark = new Comedian("Mark", 5);
                            ^
  symbol:   class Comedian
  location: class Show
6 errors
```

Comment: You need to tell us **what** tells you **which precise message**. Don't paraphrase it. Post the exact and complete message, and the relevant code it refers to.

Comment: Please provide some code, especially the package line and the class definition. Moreover, the exact error message would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compile all your source files at once. Or at least specify the classpath so that the compiler knows where to find the classes that Show depends on:

```
javac -cp kneipe kneipe/location/Show.java
```

By default, the current directory is in the classpath, so you can also move to the keipe directory, and just do

```
javac location/Show.java
```

I strongly suggest to always use the -d option to specify where the compiler should put the .class files, in a separate directory from your source files.

And in fact, once you get accustomed to how Java works, you'd better use a real build tool like gradle or Maven (but I much prefer gradle), that would make you adopt good layout conventions, and would compile, jar, etc. everything for you, with a single command.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You should name the file according to the class.</strike>

`ClassB.java` should be `Besucher.java` for example.

If it works in eclipse, then the problem is likely how you're compiling.

Here is how I would do it:

```
javac **/*.java
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify a classpath.

```
javac -cp kneipe kneipe/location/Show.java
```